# MongoDB custom methods to change one data when other two data is approved

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Employee Leave Application. When Admin approves and Manager approves I want the approval status to be updated to Approved.

```
const leaveSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
      required: [true, "It must belong to a user"],
    },
    adminApproval: {
      type: String,
      enum: ["Pending", "Approved", "Rejected"],
    },
    managerApproval: {
      type: String,
      enum: ["Pending", "Approved", "Rejected"],
    },
    approvalStatus: {
      type: String,
      enum: ["Pending", "Approved", "Rejected"],
      default: "Pending",
    },
    active: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true,
    },
  },
);
```

Comment: can you provide sample output data or elaborate your question

Comment: What I understood from your explanation is, if in database `adminApproval` & `managerApproval` are Approved, then `approvalStatus` will be Approved regardless it is `Pending` in Database?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a [middleware](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) to check this, after any time a document of that model is saved.

```
const leaveSchema = mongoose.Schema(
{
   user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
      required: [true, "It must belong to a user"],
   },
   adminApproval: {
      type: String,
      enum: ["Pending", "Approved", "Rejected"],
   },
   managerApproval: {
      type: String,
      enum: ["Pending", "Approved", "Rejected"],
   },
   approvalStatus: {
      type: String,
      enum: ["Pending", "Approved", "Rejected"],
      default: "Pending",
   },
   active: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true,
   },
});

leaveSchema.post('save', function(doc) {
   if (doc.adminApproval === 'Approved' && doc.managerApproval === 'Approved' && doc.approvalStatus !== 'Approved') {
      doc.approvalStatus = 'Approved';
      doc.save();
   }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the help sir... I did it with pre hook or whatever it's called but it worked. Thanks for taking time to help me...